# How to read a text file line by line which is not constant in shell scripting

Tags: shell-script

I need to read a text file line by line and the lines are not constant it may vary.For example

```
$ cat file1.txt
syntax error at or near "?" at character 1
syntax error at or near "[" at character 1
syntax error at or near "," at character 1
syntax error at or near "desc" at character 1
syntax error at or near "describtion" at character 1 `
```

After reading that line it must get automatically passed to the grep command and give me the result set. Since the number of lines & errors captured in the text file is not predictable. Everything needs to be done automatically

```
$ find file1.txt | xargs grep 'syntax error at or near "?" at character 1' | tail -1
```

How can I put the 2nd line,3rd line...nth line & automate it in the shell script.

Comment: When doing line-by-line operations, [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) is often the best tool for the job.

Comment: I wrote an answer but deleted because I'm a little dubious about why `grep` doesn't work...?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean you want to pass certain line numbers only to `grep`?

Comment: @JosephR. Yeah you are right..I need to pass each line only to the grep

Comment: see - that's what's left me dubious - it's usually `grep` that passes the lines.

Comment: Many people (including myself) have found this question to be incomprehensible. The brave few who tried to answer it have been told that they don’t understand, but the follow-up clarifications have not been helpful. The OP has not accepted an answer and is no longer active on Stack Exchange. While there is useful information in the answers, nobody will ever find it, since the title doesn’t even correspond well to what the question seems to be about.  This is not a useful entry in our knowledge base.

Comment: If the patterns are fixed, `grep -f PATTERNFILE ...` is the way to go. Otherwise manufacture an alternation...

Comment: ``grep -f`` was given as an answer 5½ years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read` command to read the file line by line. For example:

```
while read -r line
 do 
 [[ $line = 'syntax error at or near "?" at character 1' ]] &&  printf '%s\n' "$line"
 done < file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want `grep` to operate on lines 1 to *n* only.
For this purpose, you can use the `head` tool:

```
head -n 20 your_file | grep ...
```

This will make `grep` operate on the first 20 lines of `your_file`. Replace 20 with the *n* relevant to you.

**An alternative interpretation and answer**

It just occurred to me that you might mean that `file1.txt` contains patterns that would like `grep` to try and match. If *that* is the case, you want the `-f` option to `grep`:

```
grep -f file1.txt files_you_want_to_search
```

The `-f` option tells `grep` to obtain its patterns from `file1.txt` where it assumes one pattern per line (as you show in your post). In such cases, you may also want to add the `-F` option to ensure that any regex metacharacters in the file aren't given their special meaning but rather interpreted literally:

```
grep -Ff file1.txt files_you_want_to_search
```

Comment: Still you didn't get me correctly. What i need is a text file contains n no of rows,may be tomorrow it can be n+1 or n+10.But my script should read each line individually irrespective of number of rows it has. Also each & every row should pass to the grep command and give you the result set.

So number of rows & the type of errors captured in the text file is not constant, it varies..So the script should automatically do the process

Thanks again

Comment: @user3359124 By no. of rows, do you mean number of lines? If so, that's what `grep -f ...` does. It interprets `file1.txt` as containing many patterns with one pattern per line and it tries to run the match against each pattern in turn.

Comment: Yeah i agree with you but as you mentioned in the codings  files_you_want_to_search must be done automatically through a script, we can't manually keep on putting the lines in the grep command & check.

Comment: @user3359124 Well that can be accomplished via `find <pattern> -exec grep -Ff file1.txt' {} +` or similar as you have originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarifications in various comments, it sounds like you should be using grep's `-f` option to read a list of patterns directly from the file

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

You can add `-F` to force interpretation as literal ('fixed') strings unless the file contains regular expression patterns i.e.

```
grep -Ff file_of_lines file_to_search_for_those_lines
```

The result will be a list of all the lines in `file_to_search_for_those_lines` that match any of the strings in `file_of_lines`.